# Text align in table [bootstrap]

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

Is there a set of classes in Twitters Bootstrap Framework that aligns text?

E.g. I have some tables with $ totals that I want aligned to the right...

```
<th class="align-right">Total</th>
```

and

```
<td class="align-right">$1,000,000.00</td>
```

Comment: Why have you asked the exact same question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class="text-right"`

More reference https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/